# What's the process for merging tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was just on the main site and saw a tag: **dungeons-and-dragons-4e**

It seems to me that it is practically identical to: **dnd-4.0**

I think the tags should be merged - with the vastly more popular dnd-4.0 taking over the newcomer. I've got edit privileges, but I don't want to abuse them. Is there some process I need to follow to change these?

Comment: FYI: currently there's still some experimenting/discussion going on with the dnd tags (long vs. short). See http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/669/proposed-tag-synonyms.

Comment: To answer your question: check out [tag synonyms](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=all&tab=newest). I think you need 2.5K rep to suggest them.

Comment: @Brian Ballsun-Stanton, @ yhw42 - See why I asked in the first place? I've made the gist of these "comments" into an answer. You might want to edit that answer so it better reflects your opinion of the situation. I'll accept an answer tomorrow.

Comment: The great re-tagging just happened :)

Comment: @Brian - and dnd-4e won?  whatever

Comment: Yes, basically. I wouldn't minded had dungeons-and-dragons-4e won, but I can deal with the extant ontology.

Comment: Search engine referrals are up significantly since the retagging.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>There is currently controversy surrounding tags and synonyms, so retagging (particularly the dnd-related family) is probably not a good idea right now.</strike>

The issue has been resolved by synonyms. Thanks!